# How to get geo codes x meter from north, south, east, west from a geo location

Tags: leaflet

I want to draw a square grid on leaflet map, so i try to find the geo codes of which are x meters in north, south, east, west of the point.

In google maps api, I can use:

```
var north = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(point, 10, 0);
```

But i can't find similar function in leaflet. So how can i calculate these points?

Thank you.

Comment: Can http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#projections-l.projection.sphericalmercator or http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icrs-pointtolatlng help you ?

Comment: There is an approximate answer here : http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/2964 that could be precise enough in your case.

Comment: Here is another answer with a small implementation : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/t2f8zScvy6Y